# sql compare count from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - table 1 has list of completed tasks while table 2 has total list of tasks.  See below:

```
request_tasks
request_id
status_id

project_tasks
project_request_id
project_task_id
```

I need to count the entries in `request_tasks` (grouped by request_id) and count the entries in project_tasks (grouped by `project_task_id`) and compare the results between the two tables.

So, if `request_tasks` has 3 entries for `request_id` 1 whose `status_id = 'Completed'` but has 5 entries in `project_tasks` for `project_request_id` 1 I want to know that.

I am trying to see which `project_request_id` entries have not completed all of the tasks.

I tried

```
select project_request_id from project_tasks
where (select count(project_request_id) from project_tasks group by project_request_id) > (select count(request_id) from request_tasks)
```

however I got error sub query returns more than one row.

If I am not clear enough please advise.  I had a query that did this but a system update of my machine lost the query so I am trying to recall how I did it before.

Comment: Please reframe your question

Answer (score 0):

This should return the count of both grouped by status .. then you can add the calcutation you need

```
select a.status_id, a.count(*), b.count(*) 
from  request_tasks as a
left join project_tasks as b
group by  a.status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This 50% for your answer now explain what you want how to compare the result?!!

First count :

```
select request_id,count(*)
from request_tasks
group by request_id
```

Second count :

```
select project_request_id,count(*)
from project_tasks
group by project_request_id
```

Comment: That is my issue - I know I can do a sql query to get the count but I am having trouble figuring out how I got the two counts in the same query and did the compare

Comment: what kind of compare you want exactly post an exemple of the result that you want